# Cloning state array always empty, cant add new item to state array react native

Tags: reactjs, arrays, react-native, react-hooks, react-state

I am trying to build shopping cart like feature.
The problem is I cant add new order / update new item to react state array by cloning it.
It works if I mutate it.

```
const [data, setData] = useState({
  current_order:[],
  total:0,
});
```

`data.current_order` contains list of current items on cart.
so if new item added, it will added to the array or update the quantity if the same item already in the array.

this is my addToCart function

```js
const addToCart = (index) => {
  let tempCurrentOrder = [...data.current_order];
  let findItem = _.findIndex(data.current_order, {
    itemId: datab.displayedItems[index].id,
  });

  console.log("FindItem", tempCurrentOrder, data.current_order, findItem);
  if (findItem === -1) {
    tempCurrentOrder.push({
      itemId: datab.displayedItems[index].id,
      itemName: datab.displayedItems[index].name,
      choiceId: "",
      choiceName: "",
      choicePrice: "",
      optionIds: [],
      optionInfos: [],
      optionGroups: [],
      qty: 1,
      itemPrice: parseFloat(priceObject.price),
      subTotal: parseFloat(priceObject.price),
      priceTypeId: datab.current_price_type_id,
      note: "",
    });
  } else {
    let newQty = tempCurrentOrder[findItem].qty + 1;
    tempCurrentOrder[findItem] = {
      ...tempCurrentOrder[findItem],
      qty: newQty,
      subTotal:
        parseFloat(newQty) * parseFloat(tempCurrentOrder[findItem].itemPrice),
    };
  }
  //...
  setData((prevData) => {
    return {
      ...prevData,
      ["current_order"]: tempCurrentOrder,
      ["total"]: total,
    };
  });
};
```

`findItem` is to find if there is same id item on `data.current_order`.
The problem is `data.current_order` always empty, so adding 2nd or later item always wont work, it will stay at 1 item.

but if I change `let tempCurrentOrder = [...data.current_order]` to `let tempCurrentOrder = data.current_order`, it works.
any ideas whats wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first one, the elements of the array may still reference to the original objects. this can occur sometimes, that's why React team always recommends using the functional state update instead of trying to create a reference to the state, so both approaches are not recommended.

what you have to do is to create your logic based on the previous value of the state `prevData` that the function provides you:

```js
setData((prevData) => {
 // use "prevData.current_order" instead of "data.current_order" to create "tempCurrentOrder"
 return {
   ...prevData,
   ['current_order']: tempCurrentOrder,
   ['total']:total,
 } 
})
```